# mapbox.mapbox-terrain-dem-v1 replaces mapbox.terrain-rgb

Tags: elevation

[mapbox.mapbox-terrain-dem-v1](https://docs.mapbox.com/data/tilesets/reference/mapbox-terrain-dem-v1/)is optimized over [mapbox.terrain-rgb](https://docs.mapbox.com/data/tilesets/reference/mapbox-terrain-rgb-v1/)

But I tried to use [mapbox.mapbox-terrain-dem-v1](https://docs.mapbox.com/data/tilesets/reference/mapbox-terrain-dem-v1/) instead of [mapbox.terrain-rgb](https://docs.mapbox.com/data/tilesets/reference/mapbox-terrain-rgb-v1/) to request altitude, and returned the same data, is this right?

Is there other ways to get higher altitude accuracy?